# Is there a possibility to change intllisence for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

Hello there I was wondering if there is a way you can change the auto complete in visual studio code of `for` loop in JavaScript to be more like the auto complete in c++.
From:

```
for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
  const element = array[index];
  
}
```

to:

```
for (let i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
  /* code */
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: K&R is the established indentation convention in JS, there should not be any reason to change it ..?

Comment: you can create your own snippets.

Comment: your title asks intellisence, the question says autocomplete, but you want snippets

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Bulent and rioV8 answers and create my own snippet

```
"for loop": {
    "prefix": "for_Loop",
    "body": [
        "for(var ${1:i} = ${2:0}; i < ${3:10}; i++) {",
        "\t$4",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "for loop"
}
```